# Finding central meridian of UTM zone

Tags: coordinate-system, utm

How do I find out (calculate somehow) the central meridian for a UTM zone for which I know the zone number?

Comment: Read how the zones are defined http://www.dmap.co.uk/utmworld.htm and use Excel or something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The central meridian of a 6 degree wide UTM zone will be given by:

```
 (zone_number * 6 - 180) - 3
```

Comment: Is it something that reliably works for every zone number? I'm asking 'cause there's a script to convert lat/lng to zone number and it is said to have weird exceptions.

Comment: should work for all of the 6 degree wide ones which is all anyone except NATO use.

Comment: oh... NATO countries you mean? or you mean they have their own twisted version of UTM?

Comment: No, they are the only people who use the wierd ones north of Norway

Answer (score 1):

EPSG lists the Central Meridian in its Coordinate System Definitions:
https://epsg.io/
Or you can see all the UTM Grid Zones of the World:
http://www.dmap.co.uk/utmworld.htm

Comment: So I cannot do without external information? I was looking to have it local somehow in just one utility, 'cause in theory all the information should already be included in zone number and coordinates :/

Comment: I was looking for an algorithm basically to use in my conversions script.